# Error al generar una APK en Android Studio

Tags: android, apk

Al intentar generar un **BUILD APK** me muestra el siguiente error

> Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors
>   in the 'Messages' view.

Me dice que tengo errores en los **mensajes** no entiendo ah que se refiere con esto.
¿ Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp14.iteracion2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Busca en la pestaña inferior `Messages` y ahi te saldran los errores

Comment: @HectorSeguro te refieres al log ?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7192/Clhzbq.png

Comment: @HectorSeguro no aparece ningún error en ese apartado ... dice que se genero la apk, cosa que es cierta pero me parece extraño el mensaje

Comment: Pon el `build.gradle` y el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Revisa en lo que agrego en mi respuesta y agregalo  a tu  pregunta. @AshleyJosianne

Answer (score 0):

En `Mensajes` regularmente no muestra una cantidad de errores pero se puede encontrar el problema en `Messages Gradle Build` o en el `Event Log`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Gradle build finished with error(s)

indica errores en el `build.gradle`

Comment: gracias por comentar, he actualizado mi pregunta agregando el log ...

Comment: Se genero el .apk sin problemas agrega el build.gradle al parecer tiene errores.

Comment: Lo he agregado :D

Comment: en tu proyecto si tienes los .jar mencionados dentro del folder /libs ?

Comment: Yes! si no el problema no esta en el gradle si no no compilaría el proyecto ...